# What are the differences in the PCSX2 plugins?

Tags: games, emulation, pcsx2

I'm using the Linux build of PCSX2 on Ubuntu 19.10. This is currently version 1.5.0-0.

When I go to GS plugins, I see 3 options.

```
GSdx (GCC 8.2.0 SSE4.1/AVX) 1.1.0 [libGSdx-SSE4]
GSdx (GCC 8.2.0 SSE2/AVX) 1.1.0 [libGSdx]
GSdx (GCC 8.2.0 AVX2/AVX2) 1.1.0 [libGSdx-AVX2]
```

Could someone please explain what GSdx, SSE* and AVX* are, and what the differences between these plugins is?

Answer (score 1):

First of all GSdx comes in 5 versions,SSE2,SSSE3, SSE4.1, AVX and AVX2.Only IF your processor supports these instruction sets use highest version you can since it will be faster for you in this order from slowest to fastest: SSE2, SSSE3, SSE4.1, AVX and AVX2. The new AVX and AVX2 instructions give a minor speed up only with the software renderers of GSdx and not the hardware ones. Note: AMD users do NOT mistake SSE3 with SSSE3 (1 extra S) and SSE4A with SSE4.1, they are totally different and are NOT supported. In this case use the SSE2 flavor.